# Transitive sets and the Mostowski collapse

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

I was wondering if every set can be "transitized" - that is, made into a transitive version of itself.  Is this basically what the Mostowski collapse says?

Comment: $\{\{\{\{\}\}\},\{\}\}$.

Comment: If $y$ is transitive and has $x$ as an element, we can define the Mostowski collapse of $y$. By uniqueness, the image of $x$ does not depend on which $y$ we pick, and it is $\pi(x)=\pi[x]=\{\pi(z)\mid z\in x\}$, where $\pi$ is the collapsing map. But this set needs not be transitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not the Mostowski collapse. The collapse says a partially ordered set with certain properties is isomorphic to a transitive set with the $\in$ as the order.

You seem to ask about transitive closure, which is the smallest transitive set which includes a particular set.

Comment: Alright, thanks. Yes, I suppose that that's probably what I was thinking about.